# Perl script looking for a file with relative name

Tags: perl

I have a directory that is:

```
/foo/bar/logs_69915
```

the number of the last directory (logs_69915) changes every 5min.

the file inside that directory is named:

```
statuslog.1234.log
```

and the number on this log file also changes.

How can I set a variable to this file?

I have tried:

```
my ($file) = glob '/foo/bar/logs*/statuslog*.log';
```

with no success

Comment: @EvanMiller: Is your problem resolved? Please remember that Stack Overflow is primarily an archive of solutions to common programming problems and not simply a source of debugging help. If you have found an answer then you should accept the best solution. You can post your own answer and accept it if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get newest file using `glob()`

```
my ($file) = sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } glob("foo/bar/logs*/statuslog*.log");
```

(might be improved by caching [`-M`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) file values)